# Labeling stacked bar plot with stat="bin" in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

It would seem that ggplot2 should be able to label stacked bar plots using geom_text with the count statistics performed on subsets of a data frame in geom_bar, without having to recreate a new dataframe specifically for the labels. Is this possible?

This is what my data frame looks like:

```
> head(df.m2)
Community        Categories               Indicators  Code Scores  Condition
1  Zaragoza         Landscape Landscape \n Composition f01.1      0   Marginal
2  Zaragoza         Landscape               Windbreaks f01.1      6 Acceptable
3  Zaragoza         Landscape        Field \n Location f01.1      6 Acceptable
4  Zaragoza         Landscape     Soil \n Conservation f01.1     12    Optimal
5  Zaragoza Farmer Management         Crop \n Rotation f01.1     12    Optimal
6  Zaragoza Farmer Management        Crop \n Varieties f01.1      6 Acceptable
```

Here is the code I'm using to create my plot (notice the stat="bin" used to summarize the categorical variables):

```
p <- ggplot(df.m2, aes(Indicators, fill=Condition))
p + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-.3,12.3)) +
geom_bar(stat="bin", colour="gray", alpha=.7) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("green","yellow","red")) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,vjust= .5,hjust=1)) +
labs(x = "Farmers' Indicators", y = "Number of Rankings by Farmers") +
facet_grid(Community ~ Categories, scales = "free_x")
```

I would like to include the resulting plot, but my reputation level does not allow it. What I would like is to have the counts printed and centered on each corresponding bar.

Comment: Please [search on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[ggplot]+label+stacked+bar) and I believe you will find several nice examples that you can adapt to your own data.

Comment: @Henrik yes I did search and read for about 3 hours today before posting. None that I read addressed my question specifically. From what I can tell, the solutions are very complicated and use plyr and other such packages to manipulate the data rather than simply using ggplot's stat capabilities. If you are thinking of a particular post, you're welcome to share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `data.table` package for this. It still doesn't work with only `ggplot` capabilities. It is usually best to do data matipulation first and then use `ggplot`.

```
require(data.table)
dt.m2 <- data.table(df.m2)
dt.m2[, count:=.N, by=list(Indicators, Categories)] # create the count index 
# almost the same as before
p <- ggplot(dt.m2, aes(Indicators, fill=Condition))
p + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-.3,12.3)) +
  geom_bar(stat="bin", colour="gray", alpha=.7) +
  geom_text(aes(y=count+1, label=paste0("n=", count))) + # add text above bar
  # you may have to change the y position for this to look good
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green","yellow","red")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,vjust= .5,hjust=1)) +
  labs(x = "Farmers' Indicators", y = "Number of Rankings by Farmers") +
  facet_grid(Community ~ Categories, scales = "free_x")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll have to ask the ggplot2 folks about including stat="bin" in labeling for future versions. I haven't figured out how to make your solution work yet; errors abound, and the counts produced are not appropriate for the labeling that I want to do. But, that is more of a specific issue with my plot than generally related to the question I asked, so don't feel obliged to follow up. Thanks for the help.